# any reason (not) to delete expired ssl certificates on IIS>

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I'm getting ready to roll over some certificates on IIS 8 / Win Server 2012. I found a bunch of old expired certificates, not bound to any sites anymore. Is there any reason I should not remove these certs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should get rid of them.
Any practical use I can think of seems ethically dubious and/or inefficient.

---

To contradict myself: certain fields might be of some historical interest if you're retentive about record keeping.

Comment: You can always back them up before removing them to keep a history of your certificates. But of course you should already have that backup anyways.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to @PeterHahndorf for the backup suggestion. I'm paranoid about certs because I could imagine some hidden process that expected a cert to be around, only surfacing after it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

**Expired certificates on IIS can be removed**, since those certificates **don't provide any kind of backward-compatibility for older websites and or devices**.